# how can I set a callback for the user session timeout

Tags: meteor

When a user logs into a Meteor application a session is created. How long does it take for the session to expire after the user has closed the browser?

Does the session expire even if the browser is not closed?

Is it possible to react to the closing of a session? By invoking a callback for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for **stale session** / **session timeout** functionality for a **meteorjs** app and ran across this answer when looking for a suitable package to use.

Unfortunately the **meteor-user-status** package mentioned by Andrew doesn't seem to do a timeout.

I continued to look, found a couple of other packages, but couldn't get them to work for me - so I wrote a **very small and simple package** inspired by the others to do exactly what the questioner is asking for here i.e. force a user log out after a defined period of inactivity (whether the browser is open or not).

It does not, however, provide a callback (as it's the server that forces the logout) but this could probably be done with a Dep.autorun looking at Meteor.userId().

You can try it by typing

```
mrt add stale-session
```

And find details of how it works and how it can be configured here:

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/stale-session

and the code is open sourced here:

https://github.com/lindleycb/meteor-stale-session

Answer (score 0):

Use the package I created that tracks user status, both overall and in several different browser sessions:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

With this, you can react to both sessions being closed and users logging out (see README). I've implemented it only for logged-in users, but you can do something similar if you want to track anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using zuuk:stale-session and I too initially wished it had a callback, but I solved it with an elegant solution (IMHO).

My app has a login template that get's rendered when `if (! Meteor.user())` is true. It used to just run `this.render('login')` template which sufficed, but it still left the logged-in menu structure available. So, I switched to to Router.go('login') which has it's own layoutTemplate. So now when inactivity triggers the stale-session to delete the tokens for the user, the page goes to /login rather than just rendering the login template within whatever route was left stale.

Here's my code in router.js:

```
/** [requireLogin - make sure pay area is walled off with registration] */
var requireLogin = function() {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    // If user is not logged in render landingpage
    //this.render('login');
    Router.go('login');
    this.next();
  } else {
    //if user is logged in render whatever route was requested
    this.next();
  }
}

/**
 * Before any routing run the requireLogin function.
 * Except in the case of "landingpage".
 * Note that you can add more pages in the exceptions if you want. (e.g. About, Faq, contact...)
 */
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {
   except:['terms','privacy','about','features','home']
});
```